# Restoring a trained generator network in DCGAN

Tags: tensorflow

I have a question regarding the saving and storing models in tensorflow. I know how to save a model with tf.train.Saver() and load it later through meta file. My problem is this:

I have trained a variant of DCGAN (Deep Convolution GAN), now I want to use only generator network for other tasks. Unfortunately, I do not know how to get entire generator network such that if I feed it with a new vector z, it generates an output based on the trained parameters. All the example I found in the stackoverflow, or tensorflow documentation, just mention very simple operations with two numbers. This is not I want. I want to understand if you have trained a giant network, say with 50 layers, how to load it and feed it with new input and get the output without going into the different parameters and layers in the trained network. I want to load it as a blackbox.

Comment: Did you look into this [article](http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/). I was able to do similar things that you want to do with the help of this tutorial.

Comment: Yes, I have read it, but it does not seem it provides answer to my question. It does not say how to get the trained network. It has examples only for two variables and for only a part of the VGGNet.

Comment: The idea is same. You checkpoint your model during training. Then restore the model from the checkpoint. You can utilize the `graph.get_tensor_by_name` to access your tensors output. You can use tf.add_to_collections to access your noise input of the generator from the checkpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
generator = Generator()
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(generator=generator)
checkpoint.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))
```

where the Generator() constructor is the same as the one you used in the training.